# Setting up a watch notification in javascript for Google calendar

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

My ultimate objective is to try to add a new field with a value to an event in a google calendar when it is created (for instance, underneath description I want to create a link field with a link). I am a backend developer and am fairly new to frontend and webhooks. This problem involves:

1. that I create a new field in an event which I don't think I can do. I tried using shared extended properties but that only adds a field programmatically to the event (it doesn't display in the calendar).
2. that I create this field/add the link when an event is created. for instance, when the save button is pressed. I don't know how to create a webhook in the google calendar so I have created a separate html page which allows the user to create a meeting (not great - but an option).

This is the code for point 1:

```
var updatedEvent = 
{
    'summary': event.summary,
    'description': event.description ,
    'start': {
        'dateTime': event.start.dateTime,
        'timeZone': event.start.timeZone
    },
    'end': {
        'dateTime': event.end.dateTime,
        'timeZone': event.end.timeZone
    }, 
    'extendedProperties':
    {
        'shared': {'link': "http://mylink.com"}
    }
};

var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.patch({
    'calendarId': 'primary',
    'eventId': event['id'],
    'resource': updatedEvent});

    
request.execute(function (updatedEvent) {
        console.log(updatedEvent);
    });
}
```

This is the code for point 2:

```
const addEvent = () => {
  const title = document.getElementById("title").value;
  const desc = document.getElementById("desc").value;
  const date = document.getElementById("date").value;
  const start = document.getElementById("st").value;
  const end = document.getElementById("et").value;
  var ISOstartdate = "";

  const startTime = new Date(date + "," + start).toISOString();
  const endTime = new Date(date + "," + end).toISOString();

  var event = {
    summary: title,
    location: "Google Meet",
    description: desc,
    start: {
      dateTime: startTime,
      timeZone: "America/Los_Angeles"
    },
    end: {
      dateTime: endTime,
      timeZone: "America/Los_Angeles"
    }
  };

  console.log(event);
  var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
    calendarId: "primary",
    resource: event
  });
 
  request.execute(function(event) {
    console.log(event.htmlLink);
  });
};
```

```
async function listenForNewEvents()
{
  ++id;
  var response = gapi.client.calendar.events.watch({
    calendarId: 'primary',
    resource: {
      "id": id.toString(),
      "type": "web_hook",
      "address": "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{myname}/events", //window.location.href,
      //"token": "{myname}",
      "params.ttl": 604800
    }
  }, function(error, response) {
    if (error)
    {
      console.log(error);
      return;
    }
    console.log(response);
  }).execute();
}
```

When I call `await listenForNewEvents()` on button click, I get the following when I navigate to https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/events

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Login Required.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "required",
        "location": "Authorization",
        "locationType": "header"
      }
    ],
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "CREDENTIALS_MISSING",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "service": "calendar-json.googleapis.com",
          "method": "calendar.v3.Calendars.Get"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

If somebody could explain why I am getting this error, and perhaps how to setup the watch notification to do the task I would like it to do, that would be great. I have set things up with an API key and a web client. I authenticate every time I run my code and should am accessing my own calendar right now.

```
// Set to client ID and API key from the Developer Console
const CLIENT_ID = 'blahblah1.apps.googleusercontent.com'; 
const API_KEY = 'blahblah2';

// Discovery doc URL for APIs used by the quickstart
const DISCOVERY_DOC =
  "https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest";

// Authorization scopes required by the API; multiple scopes can be
// included, separated by spaces.
const SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar";

let tokenClient;
let gapiInited = false;
let gisInited = false;
let uuid = 1111;

document.getElementById("authorize_button").style.visibility = "hidden";
document.getElementById("signout_button").style.visibility = "hidden";
document.getElementById("event_form").style.visibility = "hidden";

/**
* Callback after api.js is loaded.
*/
function gapiLoaded() {
  gapi.load("client", initializeGapiClient);
}

/**
* Callback after the API client is loaded. Loads the
* discovery doc to initialize the API.
*/
async function initializeGapiClient() {
  await gapi.client.init({
    apiKey: API_KEY,
    discoveryDocs: [DISCOVERY_DOC]
  });
  gapiInited = true;
  maybeEnableButtons();
}

/**
* Callback after Google Identity Services are loaded.
*/
function gisLoaded() {
  tokenClient = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
    client_id: CLIENT_ID,
    scope: SCOPES,
    callback: "" // defined later
  });
  gisInited = true;
  maybeEnableButtons();
}

/**
* Enables user interaction after all libraries are loaded.
*/
function maybeEnableButtons() {
  if (gapiInited && gisInited) {
    document.getElementById("authorize_button").style.visibility = "visible";
  }
}

/**
*  Sign in the user upon button click.
*/
function handleAuthClick() {
  tokenClient.callback = async resp => {
    if (resp.error !== undefined) {
      throw resp;
    }
    document.getElementById("signout_button").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("event_form").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("authorize_button").innerText = "Refresh";
    await listUpcomingEvents();
    await listenForNewEvents();
  };

  if (gapi.client.getToken() === null) {
    // Prompt the user to select a Google Account and ask for consent to share their data
    // when establishing a new session.
    tokenClient.requestAccessToken({ prompt: "consent" });
  } else {
    // Skip display of account chooser and consent dialog for an existing session.
    tokenClient.requestAccessToken({ prompt: "" });
  }
}

/**
*  Sign out the user upon button click.
*/
function handleSignoutClick() {
  const token = gapi.client.getToken();
  if (token !== null) {
    google.accounts.oauth2.revoke(token.access_token);
    gapi.client.setToken("");
    document.getElementById("content").innerText = "";
    document.getElementById("authorize_button").innerText = "Authorize";
    document.getElementById("signout_button").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("event_form").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a post notification as follows:

```
function watchEvents() {
  console.time("watchEvents");

  tokenClient.callback = (resp) => {
    console.log(gapi.client.getToken().access_token);
    if (resp.error !== undefined) {
      console.log("caught in error");
      throw(resp);
    }
    // Call the function to set up the watch request
    const requestBody = {
      'id': uuidv4(),
      'type': 'web_hook',
      'address': 'https://....cloudfunctions.net/watchEvents2'
    };

    const requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + gapi.auth.getToken().access_token,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(requestBody)
    };

    try {
      const response = gapi.client.request({
        'path': 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events/watch',
        'params': {'ttl': '604800'},
        'body': requestBody,
        'method': 'POST',
        'headers': requestOptions.headers
      });
      console.log('Watch request sent successfully:', response);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error sending watch request:', error);
    }

    document.getElementById("watchEventsBtn").innerText = "Refresh Calendar";
  }

  // Conditionally ask users to select the Google Account they'd like to use,
  // and explicitly obtain their consent to fetch their Calendar.
  // NOTE: To request an access token a user gesture is necessary.
  if (gapi.client.getToken() === null) {
    // Prompt the user to select a Google Account and asked for consent to share their data
    // when establishing a new session.
    tokenClient.requestAccessToken({prompt: 'consent'});
  } else {
    // Skip display of account chooser and consent dialog for an existing session.
    tokenClient.requestAccessToken({prompt: ''});
  }

  console.timeEnd("watchEvents");
}
```

I am connecting with a cloud function in nodejs18 and am now stuck here:

```
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

exports.watchEvents2 = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { body } = req;
    console.log("in watch events 2");
    console.log(`body: ${JSON.stringify(body)}`);
    console.log(`body.calendarEvent: ${JSON.stringify(body.calendarEvent)}`);

    if (body.type === 'webhook_callback_verification') {
      const challenge = body.challenge;
      res.status(200).send(challenge);
      console.log("verify the webhook endpoint");
    } else if (body.type === 'notification') {
      const event = body.calendarEvent;
      const eventId = event.id;
      const eventDescription = 'http://localhost:10000';
      console.log("notification");

      // Set up the Google Calendar API client
      const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
        scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events']
      });
      const calendar = google.calendar({ version: 'v3', auth });

      // Update the event with the description
      const response = await calendar.events.patch({
        calendarId: 'primary',
        eventId: eventId,
        requestBody: {
          description: eventDescription
        }
      });

      console.log(response.data);
      console.log("end");

      res.status(200).send('Event updated successfully');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
  }
};
```

I am getting something for req but not req.body (it is empty). If you can spot the mistake, please let me know.